# Why is this Fibonacci code not correct?

Tags: c#, fibonacci

Project Euler Question 2.

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

My solution :

```
int firstNum = 1;
int secondNum = 2;
int resultNum = firstNum + secondNum;
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)
{
    firstNum = i;
    secondNum = i;

    if(resultNum == firstNum + secondNum)
    {
        sum += resultNum;
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
}
```

Why is this not correct and can you guide me into the right way of thinking?

Comment: Just debug your code.  I'd think it should be pretty clear when you see what it's doing for the first few loops.

Comment: Your `firstNum` and `secondNum` will just be `i` in each case. `resultNum` will always be 3. So you're looking for any integer values of `i` such that `i + i` is 3. That's not going to produce many answers. Your code doesn't currently produce Fibonacci numbers at all...

Comment: Should i try it with firstnum++ and secondnum++ so i can go through all of the possible numbers?

Comment: Your code does not create a fibonacci sequence. Figure that part out first.

Comment: `firstNum = secondNum; secondNum = sum;`. Also, what the...? I'm just gonna leave this here http://www.dotnetperls.com/fibonacci

Comment: If I were you I would do this recursively, this produces a lot less code, however your main problem in your code is that resultNum is stuck at 3.

Comment: @AdamV The problem description specifically specifies to start at 1,2.

Comment: @RealityDysfunction Fibonacci is actually pretty poor problem to use recursion on.  Unless you cache the values or use dynamic programming you end up re-computing the same values over and over again, thus turning an algorithm that could be linear into one that's exponential.  Computing the values up to 4 million is actually large enough that a naive recursive implementation would really struggle to compute the result.

Comment: F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) - your math is off.

Comment: @Servy Yes, your point is valid, the last time I did this was by caching the values.

Comment: @RealityDysfunction And if you're doing that then a) your memory consumption goes from O(1) to O(N) 2) performance stays about the same, perhaps a tad worse 3) the code isn't actually simpler; it's actually even more complex.  There is no reason at all to use such an approach.

Comment: is Project Euler set up in such a way so that users are encouraged not to publish results?!

Comment: @whytheq yes it is,It's a sort of competition.

Comment: @ХристоХристов ....so why are you posting the answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    int n1, n2, fib;
        //n1 = 0;
        //n2 = 1;
        n1 = 1;
        n2 = 1;

        fib = n1 + n2;

        while (fib < 4000000)
        {

            n2 = n1;
            n1 = fib;
            fib = n1 + n2;
        }
```

Then find the even fib numbers and sum it

Answer (score 1):

The fibonacci series is defined as

A<sub>0</sub> = 1,
A<sub>1</sub> = 1

A<sub>n</sub> = A<sub>n-1</sub> + A<sub>n-2</sub>

You are aiming at producing the pattern

1 2 3 5 8 13 etc

While iterating, you are going to want to adjust the input similar to a sliding window and then check to see if you have come across a valid insertion (i.e. < 4M and even)

```
int sum = 0;
int max = 4000000;
for( int n = 0; n < max ; n++ )
{
 //only sum the even numbers
 if( second % 2 == 0 ) sum += second; 

 //adjust
 int result = first + second;
 first = second;
 second = result;

 //test for numbers greater than max
 if( result > max ) break;
}

//output
Console.WriteLine(sum); //An for all even An values
```

After looking at this hopefully you can see some of the issues you came across.

You are setting your variables to the iterator `i` which is not going to produce A<sub>n</sub> as defined but instead something entirely different.

```
firstNum = i;
secondNum = i;
```

Further, you only calculate the result once. This needs to be done in the loop. Only calculating once will basically use a static value the entire time.

```
int resultNum = firstNum + secondNum;
```

The conditional statement should be testing for an even number in order to properly add to the sum, but this code will only test the static value of `resultNum`

```
if(resultNum == firstNum + secondNum)
```

Also, there needs to be some check on the sum in order to break out when the max is exceeded. 4M iterations will be too many.

---

There is even more optimization that can occur here though. Looking at the for loop, it is clear that while not used yet, the iterator can be a powerful tool.

The reason being that the fibonacci conforms to the "Golden ratio".

By making the simple observation that the fibonacci series hits an even number ever 3 iterations, the iterator can be used to skip through the series.

```
double p = (1 + Math.Pow(5,.5)) / 2;
for( int n = 3, sum = 0;;n+=3)
{
 double f = ( Math.Pow(p,n) - Math.Pow( 1 - p , n ) ) / Math.Pow(5,.5);
 if( f > 4000000 ){ 
  Console.WriteLine(sum);
  break;
 }
 sum += (int)Math.Round(f);
}
```

Comment: The problem description specifically states that it is starting at 1, 2, not 1, 1.

Comment: He doesn't want to calculate 4 million fib numbers, but rather the numbers up to 4 million.  *Big* difference there.

Comment: @Servy - I missed that caveat, edits made.

Comment: You're still calling the variable `maxIterations`, but it's not logically representing the max iterations.  Logically a `for` loop simply isn't suited to the task to begin with.  it should be a `while` loop.  As it is your `for` loop may as well just be `for(;;)` given that that n is never used for anything and you always break before hitting the end condition.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts my friend i appreciate it!

Comment: @Servy - That is an implementation style. The reason I left it like that was to hint at further optimizations. Open ended loops are not desirable, and without knowing the exact upper bounds, it is nice to have an approximation.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm not saying you should have a `for(;;)` loop, I'm saying the code in your for loop is pointless.  I specifically suggested you use a `while` loop, as it avoids the pointless code while actually semantically representing what you're doing.

Comment: @Servy - The first example does not necessarily need the for loop, but I was hoping the iteration would at least lead the OP to look at possible iterator solutions. I suppose I am not sure at times whether to give full solutions or hints. Anyway, see my edit for a more optimized version of finding these values and the sum.

Answer (score 1):

For a more modular approach (mixed with LINQ):

```
IEnumerable<Int32> Fibonacci(Int32 limit = 4000000)
{
    for (Int32 previous = 0, current = 1, next = 0; 
        current <= limit; current = next)
    {
        next = previous + current;
        previous = current;
        yield return next;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var allNumbers = Fibonacci(4000000); // 1,2,3,5,8,13,21
var evenNumbers = allNumbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0); // 2,8,34,144,610,2584
var sum = evenNumbers.Sum(); // 4613732
```

Comment: 1) You should really use more meaningful variable names.  2) The OP's requirements are to start at 1,2, not 0,1. 3) This doesn't help the OP understand what he did wrong, it's just doing his work for him 4) Someone at his level of skill is unlikely to be able to understand iterator blocks effectively enough to work with them.

Comment: @Servy: The question already had an accepted answer before I posted this so I wasn't really going for a full-on solution. All I was doing was providing a more modular answer and show how you could use LINQ and a method call to do this (instead of piling everything in to a single executable path). But thank you for your comments nonetheless.

Comment: That first point probably bothers me more than anything else.  If you want to just show how to "do it right" then you're held back by the fact that your current variable names make the code almost unreadable.

Comment: @Servy: Inever said "do it right"; you're implying that. All I said was more modular; and if I was going for readability, I would haven't have stopped at variable names--I would have made the method and variable names more concise in addition to adding a comment block to the heading. But you have enough rep, feel free to edit the answer to your satisfaction.

Answer (score -2):

Your code does not produce a Fibonacci sequence and does no check for even-valued terms

Try this instead

```
int firstNum = 1;
int secondNum = 2;

int sum = 0;

while (secondNum <= 4000000)
{
    if (secondNum % 2 == 0)
        sum += secondNum;

    int resultNum = firstNum + secondNum;
    firstNum = secondNum;
    secondNum = resultNum;
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```